# SnipCart and Authorize.net integration

Tags: testing, integration, authorize.net, snipcart

I would like to know your experience with testing integration of SnipCart with Authorize.net.

I have a site where user can purchase a digital product using SnipCart interface. Now, I want to allow access to this product only if the payment was successful. In order to do that, the site is listening to webhooks (both from SnipCart and Authorize.net).
The problem is, SnipCart does not allow you to integrate with sandbox Authorize.net account. And I would like to avoid to do real payments and refunds during the implementation phase. For now, I've just tested it manually (SnipCart in test mode and payments through Authorize.net virtual terminal).
Separately, everything works as expected.

I would like to know, how to pair Authorize.net transaction with SnipCart order? Do you know what information Snipcart uses for correlation their orders with payments (SnipCart order token, invoice number)?

I was not able to find out this information from their documentation.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: According to their website, SnipCart has native support for Authorize.Net https://snipcart.com/list-ecommerce-payment-gateways

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, they provide a native support for Authorize.net and many other payment gateways. But this configuration is only for production. In test mode, SnipCart offers their own payment gateway. So, they do not call Authorize.net, thus I cannot test full process payment (as the site is listening to webhooks from Authorize.net).